# Big JSON data to java RESTful service with TOMCAT

Tags: java, json, eclipse, tomcat

I have a Big JSON data is there any short way make it to a RESTful service
But i need a java source code for that with apache TOMCAT,..
Is there any short way,..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to make Restful web services to achieve this that return the data in JSON format... Following are the best tutorials for making restful web services.. which are quite simple..

[Tutorial 1](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/):

[Tutorial 2](http://howtodoinjava.com/restful-web-service/):

Comment: Thnaks for Responce sir,..in that i have a JSON data which is very big,... i need yo make it to java source codes is there any shot form to make it,... are the anysoftware or web sites are there to convert it,...

Comment: Yes tutorials told you making web service and represent the output in JSON format. You just need to read your data that is in json format and expose it via via web services.